# adding customed javascript analytics code to magento site

Tags: magento

i have created customized analytic code for my clients. It tracks visits and conversions. One is to be placed on the "thank you" page and one on all other pages. What is the quickest way to get my magento guys to paste the codes? Is there a header file and "thank you" page in magento for the codes. Do I write an extension for that? Any help will do. Thanks

Comment: No need for extension. You can do it within template files. Does "thank you" page have to have both codes or specific one only?

Comment: @DickLaurent : the'thank you' page have to have only one code. but having the 2 will not be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a global code to

```
/app/design/frontend/[your-interface]/[your-theme]/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

or

```
/app/design/frontend/[your-interface]/[your-theme]/template/page/html/footer.phtml
```

and the thank you page code can be placed at

```
/app/design/frontend/[your-interface]/[your-theme]/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way i can ask the users to add the code without having going into code? Just like how other ecommerce carts do it? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Will your code require some input from surfer? Please explain.

Comment: I mean i want the admin of the magento store to easily add the analytics javascript code to these files without having to open them in a text editor and adding them. thanks

Comment: Custom module will be required to do that.