# How to add GTM or Google Analytics Code/snippet manually in magento 1.9 (mainly for GTM)

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can anyone explain me how to add google tag manager code snippet to magento 1.9 manually (i.e. without extensions) in miscellaneous code the code is being placed at closing body tag. I want it to be placed after opening body tag.I want the path and which part to be edited

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837035/adding-customed-javascript-analytics-code-to-magento-site)
[Link 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-do-i-add-universal-analytics-to-my-magento-store)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok sure 
i have tried all these practices but dint get desired output   
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837035/adding-customed-javascript-analytics-code-to-magento-site)
(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-do-i-add-universal-analytics-to-my-magento-store)

Comment: I don't mean solutions that you've tried... you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the actual code you've tried, so that others can quickly get to the root of your problem.

Comment: hmm i have tried those code but there is no change or dint effect my site.code is same for magento package soo i dint know which code to show the experts here.

Comment: post some of *your* code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have got a solution for it.

```
Step 1: goto app\design\frontend\rwd(your theme package)\default\template\page and open 1column.phtml, 2column-left.phtml, 2column-right.phtml, 3column.phtml in a editor.
Step 2: Paste your GTM snippet below this code (getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>) in all the .phtml pages given in step 1.
Step 3:save the code and check ifit fires in all pages or not. 

P.S.: If your gtm does not fire in success/thank you page. paste the code in (\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\sucess.phtml) anywhere you like.
```